# MVC 4 Web API - CreateResponse(status, object) causes HTTP 500

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know more about this problem with CreateResponse?

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetProductLine(Guid id) 
{ ... // get object etc. //

// This works.
return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, productLine);

// This causes HTTP 500 Internal Server Error.
return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, (EntityObject)productLine);
```

It creates the response but something goes wrong when it is returned, so within the Web API framework.

I discovered this because I have a base API controller in which I have my own CreateResponse method which calls this.Request.CreateResponse as per above, then adds a few headers and writes some logging to the response and hands it back.

What's particularly interesting is that this works for one of my entity controllers, and not for this latest one - i.e. it just doesn't like some entities.

I can solve it by making my implementation look like this:

```
MyBaseApiController.CreateResponse<T>(HttpStatusCode statusCode, T entity) 
  where T : EntityObject
```

But nevertheless, it is odd.

**UPDATE**

Due to some DRY refactoring, my previous fix is broken. I cannot figure out how to con it into working again, so I'm stuck.

The problem does not seem to occur when returning objects from the database but when I return an object that has been received in a Put.

The problem also occurs when building my own HttpResponseMessage manually and setting the formatters.

I'll have to re-read the data from the database before returning it and hope that works - my Get is fine, so it should do.

**UPDATE 2**

Oh that's insane. Even if I get the object again from EF and return it using the same line of code as in my Get handler/action, it fails. The difference now must be in the requests - the GET formed by Chrome is fine, the PUT formed by my test client (JSON) must be tripping it up.

**UPDATE 3**

I spent the day flattening out my entities to avoid any inheritence and the problem has gone. Inheritence is a no no, it seems.

**UPDATE 4**

So I have a new WebAPI service which is returning a serializable class I've written. Although it can be serialized using the DataContractSerializer, when my request accepts XML I get a 500 but its fine when I accept JSON.

**UPDATE 5**

Using an [ITraceWriter](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api) I've managed to see the stacktrace, which ends like this:

> Exception.Source: System.Xml Exception.Message: '', hexadecimal value
>   0x05, is an invalid character. Exception.StackTrace:    at
>   System.Xml.XmlUtf8RawTextWriter.InvalidXmlChar(Int32 ch, Byte* pDst,
>   Boolean entitize)

Looks like some byte arrays in the object are screwing with the Xml formatter/serializer.

Comment: What's the exception you are getting? Some message? Some stacktrace? Something? Error 500 could mean way too many things.

Comment: Its happing within the Web API pipeline so I don't know. Do you know how I can add instrumentation to the internal workings?

Comment: I am also experiencing this issue. I debug and have enabled all CLR exceptions , and when the web api returns, my client gets a 500. However I do not get any exceptions in VS.

Comment: @Zapnologica Use tracing: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api