# How do you trace internal server errors coming from within MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Due to ongoing issues with ASP.NET MVC 4 and WebAPI, see link:

[MVC 4 Web API - CreateResponse(status, object) causes HTTP 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361810/mvc-4-web-api-createresponsestatus-object-causes-http-500)

I need to instrument the internal Web API pipeline and see what's going on.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Luke

**UPDATE **

I have an ITraceWriter now implemented and I can now see that there's an Exception property on the TraceRecord which I can dump or even break around, maybe.

Thanks, I think answers the question.

More info here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can enable all levels of tracing (from the basic, "info" tracing) for the entire stack.

If you use one of the popular libraries (i.e. nLog), you can easily write it all to file or event log if you wish.

just replace the default ITraceWriter with your custom class:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(ITraceWriter), new NLogger());
```

You'll see all kinds of internal tracing messages filling up the logs.

I blogged about that here http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/using-nlog-to-provide-custom-tracing-for-your-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: I've done all this, thanks Filip, but unfortunately it neglects to write a decent exception. I'll update the question.

Comment: Found the Exception property on TraceRecord - don't leave home without an ITraceWriter it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting:

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

[This](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2012/06/11/asp-net-web-api-exception-handling.aspx) is good post on Error Handling and tracing in Web API.

Comment: Yeah, this is on, wrapped in a conditional (DEBUG) but this particular error doesn't emit the standard ASP.NET barf page.